# <button type="button"> is not working. it don't post the data

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

> i'm trying to get the value from date-picker in post method. to select the date i need to select through button after selecting the date to get its value in post method when click on submit button it don't get any value. its value is empty.

**view**

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date range button:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" name="jamil" id="daterange-btn">
                  <span>
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date range picker
                  </span>
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
          </div>
<input type="submit" name="show" id="show"  class="btn btn-primary" value="show">
```

**controller**

```
if($this->input->post("show")){
$jam=$this->input->post("jamil");
echo($jam); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap all your HTML in the `form` tag.

You can use `bootstrap-datepciker` for that, https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

**HTML View**

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date range button:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="jamil" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" name="jamil" id="daterange-btn">
                <span>
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date range picker
        </span>
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="show" id="show" class="btn btn-primary" value="show">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$jam = $this->input->post('jamil'); // $_POST['test']
echo $jam;
```

Comment: already use the <form method="POST"> did. and it working on the other fields like <input type="text"> or other type but not working for <button type="button">

Comment: i'm using date range picker plugin in a template to can easily select date and there it coded like that <button type="button">. i cant use <input> or <a> then that plugin is not working

Comment: wait you can achieve it without using ajax, wait for my updated answer

Comment: which datepicker, you are using?

Comment: date range button

Comment: brother, which library you are using for date-picker?

Comment: sorry bro :( dont know about the library

Comment: use this library, https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: you can also access it via `input`

Comment: glad to help you